# How (if at all) can binary operator methods of numpy arrays be overridden by the right operand?

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading

I have a custom class which defines custom, commutative, behaviour for the binary `+` operator:

```
class foo(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        ...
    __radd__ = __add__
```

It is designed to deal with scalars and with `numpy` arrays in its own way---a way that is intentionally different from the way `numpy` adds arrays.

If I start with the following:

```
f = foo()
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
c = 4
```

then all is well if I do `f + a`,  `f + c` or `c + f`, in the sense that I get the custom behaviour I want in all cases.  However `a + f` gets me a different result (and in some situations an exception) because the `numpy` array method `a.__add__` takes over.  I understand that `__radd__` is "only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation" per the Python docs. I also read somewhere that this is overridden if `a.__add__` returns `NotImplemented`.

So is there any way of telling `numpy` "hey, I got this,  you should return `NotImplemented` when asked to add a `foo`"?    In Matlab this would be accomplished by `superiorto`.  Is there any equivalent in `numpy`? (NB: I don't want to have to subclass `numpy.ndarray`---I want to be able to deal with `numpy` arrays as they come.)

[In an ideal world I would like to be able to cope with native Python objects in the same way, such that  `[1,2,3] + foo()`  gave the same result as `foo() + [1,2,3]`---but I'm guessing it's got to be impossible to disable `list.__add__` selectively based on the class of the right operand. Right?]