# python prevent operator call

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading, operators

I've a class `CustomArray` similar to `numpy.ndarray`. It overloads a bunch of arithmetic operators like `__add__`, `__mul__` etc. Since people will most likely use it in conjunction with numpy I'm afraid that from time to time `numpy.ndarray` operators will be called instead of `CustomArray`. Worst thing is that they actually work and produce some unwanted result.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = CustomArray([1, 2, 3])
c = a + b  # np.ndarray.__add__ will be called!
```

Is there a way to prevent that? So interpreter will either raise an error or will always prefer `CustomArray` operator overloads.

Comment: Similar recent question (but no answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600049/can-binary-operator-methods-of-numpy-arrays-be-overridden-by-the-right-operand

Comment: No, there isn't. If the left-hand operand implements the method, it gets executed first.

Comment: @jonrsharpe mb there is a way to modify `CustomArray` so that numpy will produce some reasonable error message.

Comment: It's unclear what you'd consider *"some reasonable error message"*. Unless it is [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) the other methods won't be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NumPy 1.13, there's the new [`__array_ufunc__` API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_ufunc__). This API is **provisional**, and backward compatibility is not yet guaranteed.

`numpy.ndarray` delegates to NumPy ufuncs for its operators, and NumPy ufuncs will delegate to `__array_ufunc__` to implement ufunc behavior, if they find it. The rules for this skip `numpy.ndarray.__array_ufunc__`, so if you implement your own `__array_ufunc__`, it will always take priority when using your instances with NumPy arrays.

If you want to disable all ufuncs on your objects, you can set `__array_ufunc__ = None` on your class:

```
class CustomArray(...):
    __array_ufunc__ = None
```

Alternatively, if you want to implement it, the signature is

```
def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
```

where for the case you're interested in,

- `ufunc` is the ufunc object (for example, `numpy.add` for `+`),
- `method` is `"__call__"`,
- `inputs` is the tuple `(left operand, right operand)`, and
- `kwargs` is empty.

For more advanced cases, `method`, `inputs`, and `kwargs` may be different, so `return NotImplemented` if you don't want to deal with those cases.

As an example, if you want to overload `+` with NumPy arrays, you could write

```
def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
    if ufunc is not numpy.add:
        return NotImplemented
    if method != "__call__":
        return NotImplemented
    if kwargs:
        return NotImplemented
    return my_addition_logic(*inputs)
```

You will also still need to implement `__add__`.

Comment: Can't get it to work for some reason, does it work only if I subclass from np.ndarray?

Comment: @DikobrAz: No, subclassing `numpy.ndarray` is specifically not a requirement.